# Timer not working in background in swift 4, is there any way to work?

Tags: ios, timer, nstimer, swift4

I tried below code but didn't work in background, it's working fine in for ground. It's start from where we leave app in background.

```
self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

func updateTimer()
{
    let minute = (time / 60) % 60
    let second = time % 60
    let hours = (time / 3600)
    time += 1
    self.lblTIme.text = String(format: "%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minute, second)
}
```

Comment: `Timer` is scheduled by the app runloop, so I imagine the reason it doesn't work properly in the background is because the runloop isn't active. See [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer)

Comment: You can't run the timer when your app is suspended. The trick to grab the time when your app moves to the background and calculate the elapsed time when your app comes back to the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

The trick to getting around this is by not managing the time on your own, let iOS do it for you.

Save the time (from when you want to start counting) in a Date, and calculate the elapsed time based on the difference in the saved date and the current date (`Date()`).

This is much more cleaner to code, and helps you get around the timer stopping when the app is backgrounded.

Comment: Are you trying to make a count up timer?

Comment: If you want to be immune against date changes you will need to use the system uptime as reference in you implementation.